I am unable to host flask applications
I am confused with hosting flask application. I am a student and I can only prefer the free hosting websites. also please suggest any good easy to host websites too (free).
I use to use vercel, but i do not like the lengthy domain name, so recently i tried other different sites like render, but I just couldn't host them. Some how or there other there are always some error.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
